# Communicating between Ruby processes, loops

Tags: ruby, multithreading, process, fork

I have a Ruby application which must run 24/7 to process information for a web API, both of which are operating on Google Compute Engine on a Debian Instance - the API is served by Sinatra. When I run this script in `loop`, it uses up the 1-core vCPU. Using a message queuing system like RabbitMQ to pass messages from the API to the backend script seems to me to skip a learning opportunity for communicating between Ruby scripts natively.

1. How do I keep a script dormant, i.e. awaiting instruction but not consuming memory 99% CPU? I'm assuming it's not going to be in an infinite loop, but I'm stumped on this.
2. How would it be best to communicate this message from one script to another? I read about Kernel#Select and forking of subprocesses, but I haven't encountered any definitive or comprehensible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Forking may indeed be a good solution for you, and you only need to understand three system calls to make good use of it: fork(), waitpid() and exec(). I'm not a Ruby guy, so hopefully my C-like explanation will make enough sense for you to fill in the blanks.

The way **fork()** works is by the operating system making a byte-for-byte copy of the calling process' virtual memory space as it was when fork() was called and carving out new memory to place the copy into. This creates a new process with its parent's exact state--except for that the child process' fork() call returns 0, while the parent's returns the PID of the new child process. This allows the child process to know that it is a child, and the parent process to know who its children are.

While fork() copies its caller's process image, the **exec()** system call replaces its caller's process image with a brand new one, as specified by its arguments.

The **waitpid()** system call is used by the parent process to wait for a return value from a specific child process (one whose process ID was returned to the parent by the fork() call), and then properly log the process' completion with the OS. Even if you don't need your child process' return value, you should call waitpid() on it anyway so you don't end up accumulating "zombie processes."

Again, I'm not a Ruby guy, so hopefully my C-like pseudocode makes sense. Consider the following server:

```
while(1) { # an infinite loop
  # Wait for and accept connections from your web API.
  pid = fork(); # fork() returns a process ID number

  # If fork() returns a negative number, something went wrong.
  if(pid < 0) {
    exit(1);
  }

  # If fork() returns 0, this is the child process.
  else if(pid == 0) {
    # Remember that because fork() copies your program's state,
    # you can use variables you assigned before the fork to
    # send to the new process as arguments.
    exec(./processingscript.rb, "processingscript.rb", arg1, arg2, arg3, ...);
  }

  # If fork() returns a number greater than 0 (the PID of the forked
  # child process), this is the parent process.
  else if(pid > 0) {
    childreturnvalue = waitpid(pid); # parent process hangs here until
                                     # the process with the ID number
                                     # pid returns.    
  }
}
```

Written this way, your CPU-intenive script only runs when a connection is received from the web API. It does its processing and then terminates, waiting to be called again. You can also specify "no hang" options for waitpid() so that you can fork multiple instances of your processing script concurrently without having your server hang every time it needs to wait for an instance of that script to complete.

Hope this helps! Perhaps somebody who knows Ruby can edit this to be a bit more idiomatic to the language.